# ¿Diferencias entre .map y .flatMap?

Tags: java, java-stream

Estoy trabajando con Streams(Java 8) y cuando utilizo el método `.stream()`  no me queda claro la diferencia entre `.map` y `.flatMap`. ¿Qué diferencias hay entre estos métodos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La diferencia es que `map()` devuelve el mismo número de elementos que el Stream de entrada ya que es simplemente una proyección de los elementos de entrada. Es decir cada elemento de entrada se transforma en un elemento de salida.

Por otro lado `.flatMap()`, proyecta una lista de elementos de cada elemento original y los concatena en un único *stream*.

Por ejemplo:

## map()

```
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

List<Integer> cuadrados = numeros
  .stream()
  .map( x -> x * x)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Integer n : cuadrados) {
  System.out.println(n);
}

// Imprime el cuadrado de los números de entrada. 4 elementos de entrada, 4 de salida
// 1
// 4
// 9
// 16
```

## flatMap()

```
List<List<Integer>> listaBidimensional = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(Arrays.asList(
  new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2)),
  new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4))
));
// [
//   [1, 2],
//   [3, 4]
// ]


List<Integer> listaAplanada = listaBidimensional
  .stream()
  .flatMap( listaInterna -> listaInterna.stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());


for (Integer n : listaAplanada) {
  System.out.println(n);
}

// Imprime los números de entrada en una sola lista de 1 dimensión.
// 2 elementos de entrada (2 listas), 4 de salida
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , me ha servido bastante!

Comment: Ayudando se aprende bastante también

Answer (score 4):

Pues la diferencia es que *.map* produce un valor de salida por cada valor de entrada y *.flatmap* produce de cero a n valores de salida por cada valor de entrada, mas o menos de la siguiente forma:

**map:: Stream T (I -> O)** 
**flapmap:: Stream T (I -> Stream O)**

Te adjunto un código de ejemplo:

```
public class Developer {
  private String name;
  private Set<String> languages;

  public Developer(String name) {
    this.languages = new HashSet<>();
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void add(String language) {
    this.languages.add(language);
  }

  public Set<String> getLanguages() {
    return languages;
  }
}

public class FlatMapTest {
  @Test
  public void flatMap() {
    List<Developer> team = new ArrayList<>();
    Developer polyglot = new Developer("experto");
    polyglot.add("clojure");
    polyglot.add("scala");
    polyglot.add("groovy");
    polyglot.add("go");

    Developer busy = new Developer("estandard");
    busy.add("java");
    busy.add("javascript");

    Developer becario = new Developer("becario");

    team.add(polyglot);
    team.add(busy);
    team.add(becario);

    List<String> teamLanguages = team.stream().
         map(d -> d.getLanguages()).
         flatMap(l -> l.stream()).
         collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertTrue(teamLanguages.containsAll(polyglot.getLanguages()));
    assertTrue(teamLanguages.containsAll(busy.getLanguages()));

  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , me ha servido